# [del]eting an item from a JSON dictionary leaves an empty dict: `{}`. How do I remove it completely?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to delete a dictionary item nested within a list, in a dict.
After I `del` the object, the modified dictionary will contain an empty dictionary: `{}` in the place of the deleted object.
Here is the code I am using:

```
json_dict = {"top_key": "top_value", "bottom_key": [{"list_dict": "list_dict_value"},{"list_dict1": "list_dict_value1"}]}

print("initial:", json_dict)

def delete(list_dict):
    for i in json_dict["bottom_key"]:
        if list_dict in i:
            del i[list_dict]


delete("list_dict")
print("final:", json_dict)
```

The final print will return:
`final: {'bottom_key': [{}, {'list_dict1': 'list_dict_value1'}], 'top_key': 'top_value'}
(pw-retriever) simon@[pw-retriever](fix_del_ls)`

I am trying to find a way to remove the `{}` in addition to the key:value pair, in one go.

edit: an explanation as to what the heck is going on would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do all the inner dicts only have one key?

Comment: @schwobaseggl The inner dictionaries that reside inside the list are all one-key : one-value

Comment: You could do `del i`, but to do that safely you'd have to iterate over the list in reverse. Or make a copy of the list to iterate over, as schwobaseggl suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
for i in json_dict["bottom_key"][:]:  # important: iterate a shallow copy
    if list_dict in i:
        json_dict["bottom_key"].remove(i)
```

However, since removing from a list is `O(N)` and you might have to remove multiple elements, you might consider just rebuilding it from scratch in one go:

```
json_dict["bottom_key"] = [d for d in json_dict["bottom_key"] if list_dict not in d]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Good to know :) But sometimes someone else has just posted an answer too similar to keep mine. Or sth has come up preventing you from polishing your answer so you'd rather remove it than leave it as is.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Regarding the "# important:" comment: are you simply pointing out that you've made a shallow copy?

Comment: Yup. Without the `[:]` slice the behaviour can turn ugly as you are removing from the collection that you are iterating.

Comment: @simonsays  As I said above, it's not safe to remove stuff from a list that you're iterating over in the forward direction. It's like sawing off a tree branch that you're sitting on. If you cut on the wrong side, bad things happen. ;) Play around with some examples and you'll see what I mean. And you can see some examples here: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0):

Constructing further on basis of your structure, `del` using the index of the `dict`, like follows :

```
def delete(list_dict):
    for i,ele in enumerate(json_dict["bottom_key"][:]) :
        if list_dict in ele:
            del json_dict["bottom_key"][i]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : initial: {'top_key': 'top_value', 'bottom_key': [{'list_dict': 'list_dict_value'}, {'list_dict1': 'list_dict_value1'}]}

>>> delete("list_dict")

OUT : final: {'top_key': 'top_value', 'bottom_key': [{'list_dict1': 'list_dict_value1'}]}
```

EDIT : [schwobaseggl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744744/7550472) idea of reconstructing the dictionary is better than deleting the elements as the previous one can lead to logical mistakes.

Comment: This won't work properly if there are more instances to be deleted. You are removing stuff while iterating... the indexes won't match anymore.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, true. As you mention, using a shallow copy is better. Thanks for pointing it out.